how to repeat command sequence in IDA
How do I run the following command palette action command sequence a 100 times in IDA? DeclareStructVar, NavLineDown.
I can write a for loop as an IDC script to the bottom row of the GUI, something like this: auto i; for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { Message("Hello %d\n", i); }. But what do I write instead of Message(...)?

Closest I know of is process_ui_action. However, you are doing it wrong (tm) )  If you need to declare 100 identical members of a structure, just press '*' to make an array, set its length to 100 and uncheck "create an array" checkbox (same works with data and with types). It will create 100 individual items for you
